# Use custom image in DataTemplate and support themes

Tags: c#, data-binding, winrt-xaml

I have a data template like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LeftIconTileTemplate">
    <Grid Height="135" Width="350" Margin="0" Background="{ThemeResource MyTileTextBackground}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Width="100" Height="100"  Margin="0,7,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,0,12,12" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

             . . .

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use this to display the contents of an observable collection. In the data objects, there is a property that I can use to pick an icon for the  element. Right now, that is a path to a PNG file in my app resources.

I have a ThemeResource resource dictionary and in it, I have different images for certain icons that I want to display. How can I change the code above so that I can bind some property of the Image such that it changes depending on the theme that the user selects?

I created a BitmapImage for an icon in each of the light, dark, and default ThemeResource sections. I then created a Style in my XAML file that would set the Image Source property of an Image. And finally, I have a Style property in my data object that I bind to in the Image in the DataTemplate. That, and a few other things that I tried, all work fine with the exception that a theme change doesn't make the icon image change. The rest of the DataTemplate changes but I can't manage to both specify an icon in the data object and also have the icon change dynamically when the theme changes.

My next alternative is to do away with the DataTemplate and just use a few nested Styles to create look of the DataTemplate but with each having a separate icon. Then I can fill the page in the OnnavigatedTo() function and have it all work fine. The data binding with a DataTemplate and theme selection just don't seem to work together.

In summary; how can I create a data template that has runtime customization of the Image element using binding to a data object in the C# code, while also having that customized Image element get updated when the theme changes?